# Shopify Admin Panel Via API?

Tags: api, shopify

Can I add stuff (links) (scripts) etc to the shopify admin panel, they way I can do that for the front-end shop, I want to be able to provide the admin a functionality on the admin pages, is it possible with the shopify API? by editing themes? do they allow to edit themes that display admin ?

very new to shopify Thanks in advance.

Abid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only add links on certain places within the Shopify admin. You can configure those links in your Shopify Partner Dashboard. Within the Partner Dashboard navigate to your App, click on "Edit spp settings", there you'll find "Shop admin links" section.

To add a link you also have to specify where the link should appear within the Shopify admin.

Answer (score -2):

Sure. Fire up your partner account, create an App, and inject as many links as you need into a shop at the key end points available. There are numerous opportunities to do this.

Comment: I want to inject in the admin panel not in the shop ? I don't see how that is possible?

Comment: What is this mysterious admin panel you speak of? A shop admin is a shop admin. Are you sure you're on the right forum topic here?

Comment: a shop front-end is what the customer sees, an admin panel is what the shop owner sees, could you point me to a single shopify app that adds stuff to the admin panel for the shop owner, I know you can add a link to selected positions only, you can't add functionality, moddify what admin sees via liquid temsplates, that all for the customer facing side.

Comment: lets say I want to build an app that allows the admin to classify each of their products as "A" or "B" and I want this to happen within the shopify admin, could you point to a link, support forum which shows this can be done ?

Comment: You cannot do that. Just do it in your App like everyone else.